# Are fonts specific to one program or shared with all of them?

Tags: windows, fonts

I used Photoshop and Advanced PDF Editor (separate program) and there are several files I am working on that state I do not have the fonts installed.

Are missing fonts something that I must install for each program that requires them or is it a case where I simply install the fonts to Windows and all programs now have access to them?

Comment: If you receive a document and the document's font is not installed on your system, the system will generally use a similar generic font to display or print the document. The problem comes if you want to edit the document. Without the same font, your edit won't exactly match. There are thousands of fonts; it doesn't make sense to incur the overhead installing every font on the planet so that you're ready when the odd document comes along. It makes more sense to install these fonts when and if needed.

Answer (score 0):

To your first question yes when you install a font to the system it is available to every program in the system.

Your second question while you could install ALL THE FONTS!!!! it is typically frowned upon. Because all of them need to load at system startup and can bog down your system. For finding additional fonts I would recommend checking out fontspring, google fonts, and Adobe then install the ones you need.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, when you install a font in Windows system it'll be available to every program installed in the same Windows platform as per my knowledge.

When it comes to finding the fonts you need I'm recommending you to do a simple Google search or try to search in following Font directories.

- [Google Web Fonts](https://fonts.google.com/)
- [Fonts.com](https://www.fonts.com/browse)